# Jobs Section inset always has same results

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

I find the section to be always oscillating between the same 3-4 jobs. It's been the same 3-4 jobs for literally years.

So either it's unscrupulous HR departments at these companies paying some menial $$$ to lure people to a non-existing job for the sake of conducting a meaningless interview to keep their files busy, or the technology is broken and it's simply not updating.

Or I am stuck in a groundhog day type situation...

Comment: What are these same 3-4 jobs? And which section are you referring to? I haven't noticed any recurring jobs whenever I've looked, but maybe I'm just not observant enough.